# Migrating data from Teradata to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, teradata

I'm running Teradata express on VMWare player. In order to migrate the data to BigQuery I'm trying to follow the official documentation capturing BigQuery transfer job.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/teradata-migration

I have downloaded the required jars and trying to start the migration process alfer successful initialization. Providing the config file contents generated after successful initialization.

```
TDExpress1620_Sles11:~/Desktop # cat testpath/bq.config
{
  "agent-id": "84f7cf04-2133-4c5a-ae43-dd22a30281ba",
  "transfer-configuration": {
    "project-id": "106730138445",
    "location": "us",
    "id": "5e1c7eda-0000-249c-aab6-94eb2c06245a"
  },
  "source-type": "teradata",
  "console-log": false,
  "silent": false,
  "teradata-config": {
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost"
    },
    "local-processing-space": "testpath",
    "database-credentials-file-path": "",
    "max-local-storage": "200GB",
    "gcs-upload-chunk-size": "32MB",
    "use-tpt": false,
    "max-sessions": 0,
    "spool-mode": "NoSpool",
    "max-parallel-upload": 1,
    "max-parallel-extract-threads": 1,
    "session-charset": "UTF8",
    "max-unload-file-size": "2GB"
  }
```

After running the command to start the migration process, I come across below error.

```
TDExpress1620_Sles11:~/Desktop # java -cp terajdbc4.jar:mirroring-agent.jar com.google.cloud.bigquery.dms.Agent --configuration-file=testpath/bq.config
Reading data from gs://data_transfer_agent/latest/version
WARNING: Failed to get the latest released agent version with error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1349)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:398)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1024)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:670)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.addListener(ForwardingListenableFuture.java:45)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture.addListener(ApiFutureToListenableFuture.java:52)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1330)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.addCallback(ApiFutures.java:63)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:67)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:86)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.datatransfer.v1.DataTransferServiceClient.getTransferConfig(DataTransferServiceClient.java:741)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.datatransfer.v1.DataTransferServiceClient.getTransferConfig(DataTransferServiceClient.java:718)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.dms.gcloud.TransferServiceClient.getTransferConfig(TransferServiceClient.java:62)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.dms.gcloud.TransferServiceClient.getDestinationBucketName(TransferServiceClient.java:94)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.dms.Agent.main(Agent.java:235)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:500)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:65)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:592)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:508)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:632)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedNoRouteToHostException: null: bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4009:810:0:0:0:200a:443
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:104)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.connect(Socket.java:257)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:730)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:715)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.connect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:557)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1340)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:532)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:517)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.connect(WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.java:136)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:532)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1000(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$9.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:522)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:333)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException
    ... 19 more
```

Please let me know if somebody has successfully implemented the same or able to figure out the exact issue being faced by me.

Comment: You may need to configure a default gateway and/or DNS to allow internet access from the VMware image.

Comment: I believe this has been configured correctly. I'm able to see the pings working `ping google.com`.

Comment: I have also verified that ports 1025 and 5298 are open. Absolutely no issues with Internet connectivity inside VM. I would also like to highlight that latest teradata jdbc bundle doesn't have `tdgssconfig.jar`. Refer: https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver

Comment: I have tried initialising and starting the migration using latest jdbc jar as well but still facing same issues.

Comment: The error message you provided is generally related to authentication issues and the cause can be GCP credentials or SSL config, among other issues. 

However, I looked through the tutorial you followed and I believe there is a typo in the command provided in the _Running agent section_ : 
_--configuration-file=config.json_ **_inestead of_** --configuration_file=config.json. Could you please check that in you code?

Comment: Agent suggests that `--configuration-file=config.json` is the correct option.

Comment: @BalajeeVenkatesh, did you test I suggested? Please, let me know.

Comment: Yes, it didn't support `--configuration_file=config.json`.

Comment: If that was not the issue. Have you checked the on-prem requirement, including your Google Cloud credentials? LINK:https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/teradata-migration#on-premises_requirements